# How to iterate in JavaScript like bash?

Tags: javascript, bash, for-loop, iteration

In bash I can do:

```
for i in {0..2}; do echo x$i; done
```

In JS:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
  console.log(x$i);
 };
```

Obviously does not work.

Is there a way around that is as simplified as bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES2015 gives you template literals:

```
console.log(`x${i}`);
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I understand you just want to loop from data you already have? Or just for 3?

```js
var x = "";
for(var i = 1; i < 4; i += 1) {
  x += i + " ";
}
console.log(x);
```

Would loop until it reaches 3